# Highcharts: x axis label issue with a single data point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Checks out following examples,

- [jsfiddle example one](http://jsfiddle.net/06wcuatb/1/) with multiple data point
- [jsfiddle example two](http://jsfiddle.net/t3ujt9xz/) with a single data point

The first example with multiple data point looks good and it is exactly what I need: x axis label of each data point is a year, i.e., `2015`, `2016`, `2017`.

However, the second example which contains a single data point, its x axis label is `08:00:00.000`.

The question is how I could make x axis label in first example displays `2015` instead of `08:00:00.000`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why with a single point the display format is different, but you can force the format in the xAsis - labels property (this is however clearly specified in docs and many other questions: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        format: '{value:%Y}',
        align: 'left'
    }
}
```

In the chart there is also a navigator, and you must set even there the format:

```
navigator: {
    enabled: true,
    adaptToUpdatedData: false,
    height: 20,
        xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%Y}',
            align: 'left'
        }
    }
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ujt9xz/2/